# pdo pagination limit error

Tags: php, pdo, pagination

I have a pagination script and I am trying to change the mysql database into pdo database but I get this error; SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESCLIMIT -2,2' at line 1

The part of code what gives me troubles is;

```
$limit = "LIMIT ".($page-1)*$perPage.",$perPage";
//$offset = ($page - 1)  * $perPage;
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT image_id FROM images WHERE album_id= ? ORDER BY image_id DESC'.$limit);
$query->bindValue(1, $album_id);
//$query->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
try{
$query->execute();
}catch (PDOException $e){
die($e->getMessage());
}
```

I searched on google for solutions but my pdo knowledge is not good enough to use it right. I got errors like; SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens, because of `$query->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

I don't know how to solve this, can anybody help me?
Thanks...

Comment: according to your error, you have a problem with the term `DESCLIMIT`, which is not proper SQL, I believe you were going for `DESC LIMIT`. Just put a space at the end of your prepare statement AFTER `DESC`.

Comment: I did ORDER BY image_id DESC' .$limit); but it makes no change. A space before the ' it makes the limit disappear.

Comment: It should look like `ORDER BY image_id DESC ' . $limit);`. Everything before `ORDER_BY` should be fine.

Comment: If I move the ' like you said the end of the error looks like this;  for the right syntax to use near '-2,2' at line 1

Comment: you cannot have negative values in the `LIMIT`. the first number in `LIMIT` tells SQL where to start, and the second number tells SQL how many rows you want returned.

Answer (score 1):

It seems mysql don't like negative offsets. You can make it this way

```
$limit = ($page-1)*$perPage;
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
$sql  = 'SELECT image_id FROM images WHERE album_id=? ORDER BY image_id DESC LIMIT ?,?';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$album_id,$limit,$perPage]);
$ids  = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Comment: Unfortunately no differences. The end of the error looks now like this; for the right syntax to use near '-2,2' at line 1

Answer (score -1):

In the tutorial the first query was `$count_query = $db->prepare('SELECT NULL FROM images where album_id= ?');`
That worked in the tutorial but not here, I think that gave the negative value.
I changed this into `$count_query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM images where album_id= ?');`
and the error is gone. Other errors is showing up now, hopefully I can solve that. 
Thanks for helping me solve this error.